# Is it possible to interrupt the authentication/authorization process in OpenAM based on IdP assertion attribute value?

Tags: authorization, saml-2.0, openam

I´m using OpenAM as hosted SP and need to evaluate the value of one attribute in the remote IdP assertion in order to replicate the same behavior seen in LDAP authentication chain, when user filter is set to `("SpecialAttribute"="TRUE")`. The attribute is available in the assertion, and I added it in SP/Assertion Processing/Attribute Mapper [image],

Now I don´t know what to do. Is this, at least, the right direction ?
Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

From your description I suspect you want to achieve that when the SAML response includes the attribute `SpecialAttribute` with value `TRUE`, the SAML SSO flow should be successfull and when the value is different or when the attribute is missing, the SAML SSO flow should fail.
Given this suspicion, you need to create an [SAML2 Service Provider Adapter](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/apidocs/com/sun/identity/saml2/plugins/SAML2ServiceProviderAdapter.html) implementation and check the SAML response in the `preSingleSignOnProcess` method. If the attribute does not meet the criteria, throw a proper `SAML2Exception`